# How to Specify a SQL Server Computed Column in TypeORM Entities?

Tags: node.js, sql-server, database, orm, typeorm

I want to create a [SQL Server table with computed columns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table?view=sql-server-ver15) using TypeORM entities, but I could not find computed columns in the TypeORM documentation under the section of [column types for mssql](https://typeorm.io/#/entities/column-types-for-mssql).

How to set a column type as a computed column in TypeORM entities?

If it is not supported yet in TypeORM, is there any workaround? Thank you

[image: Column types for mssql]

Comment: A computed column still has a type like int or varchar

Comment: How do I tell TypeORM to create a varchar computed column in TypeORM entity? If I set type as varchar only, TypeORM wouldn't know to create a computed column in mssql table.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/1822#issuecomment-573492291) helps. Seems like its [not yet supported](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/296)